# Subtract from purchase and sale s table for found balance

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join

I have two tables: table one Purchase and another sales table, actually I need balance using subtract two table, subtract sales from table Purchase. My code is given below

> ```
> create table purchase(
> id  number(10) primary key,
> name varchar2(10),
> p_qty number(10)
> );
> ```

and insert data :

> ```
> insert into purchase values(01,'productB',235);
> insert into purchase values(04,'productC',394);
> insert into purchase values(05,'productD',381);
> insert into purchase values(08,'productE',357);
> insert into purchase values(09,'productF',389);
> insert into purchase values(10,'productQ',336);
> ```

another  table: Sales

> ```
> create table  sales(
>  id number(10),
>  s_qty number(10),
>  constraint pid_pk foreign key (id)REFERENCES purchase(id)
> );
> ```

insert data to salse table :

> ```
> insert into sales values(01,34);
> insert into sales values(04,54);
> insert into sales values(05,44);
> insert into sales values(09,50);
> insert into sales values(01,3);
> insert into sales values(04,4);
> insert into sales values(05,5);
> insert into sales values(09,53);
> insert into sales values(01,2);
> insert into sales values(04,2);
> insert into sales values(05,2);
> insert into sales values(09,2);
> insert into sales values(01,4);
> insert into sales values(04,9);
> insert into sales values(05,11);
> insert into sales values(09,7);
> ```

and I have using two query

Query 1:

```
 select  id,name,sum(p_qty) as p_total  from purchase  group by id,name;
```

> ```
> ID    NAME      P_TOTAL
> 5     productD    381
> 10    productQ    336
> 4     productC    394
> 1     productB    235
> 8     productE    357
> 9     productF    389
> ```

QUERY2:

> ```
> select id,sum(s_qty) as s_total from sales group by id;`
>
> ID    S_TOTAL
> 1     43
> 4     69
> 5     62
> 9     112
> ```

NOW I Want to below the table for balance each item

> ```
> ID    NAME      P_TOTAL      S_TOTAL  BALANCE
> 5    productD    381          62       319
> 4    productC    394          69       325
> 1    productB    235          43       192
> 9    productF    389          112      277
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
  SELECT p.id, p.name, p.p_total, s.s_total, 
  p.p_total - s.s_total AS balance
  FROM (select id, name, sum(p_qty) as p_total FROM purchase 
  GROUP BY id, name) p
  INNER JOIN (select id, sum(s_qty) as s_total FROM sales 
  GROUP BY id) s
  ON s.ID = p.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Take the two queries you already have and join them together:

```
SELECT p.ID,
       p.NAME,
       p.P_TOTAL,
       s.S_TOTAL,
       p.P_TOTAL - s.S_TOTAL AS BALANCE
  FROM (select id, name, sum(p_qty) as p_total
          from purchase
          group by id, name) p
  INNER JOIN (select id, sum(s_qty) as s_total
                from sales
                group by id) s
    ON s.ID = p.ID
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks  all, all code are  working  well , i can   can select only one  answer , so i select first answer , again thanks @Bob Jarvis,Gordon Linoff,nish

Answer (score 0):

> I Want to below the table for balance each item

You way you want the balance for each item, but you only show the balance for the items with sales.

If you want each item that has been purchased, you can use `left join` with subqueries:

```
select p.id, p.name, p_total, coalesce(s_total, 0),
       (p_total - coalesce(s_total, 0)) as balance
from (select id, name, sum(p_qty) as p_total
      from purchase
      group by id,name
     ) p left join
     (select id, sum(s_qty) as s_total
      from sales
      group by id
     ) s
     on p.id = s.id;
```

If you want each item that has sales, then just use `inner join`.